# What was the out-of-universe reason to destroy this race?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the last episode of SG-1

> the Asgards commit mass suicide and given all their knowledge to the Tau'ri

What was the out of universe reason for taking them out of the equation? At that point Atlantis was still going on and I'm assuming Universe would be in someone's head, so what did the writer / producers gain from making that decision and why did they think that was needed?

Comment: Having them kill themselves takes them out of the human vs wraith fight.

Comment: There was a long lead up to the end of the Asgard. Since their introduction, they have been a race in decline with repeated failures in attempting to reinvigorate their genetic line. Eventually passing the torch to humanity was alluded to more than once, starting with the Season 2 episode "The Fifth Race".

Comment: SGA's "Evil Asgard" were already in the pipeline, and if SGA had gone on past S5, they were going to become a major villain (Mallozzi says, I think on Gateworld).  The "Good Asgard" would easily be able to get rid of them instantly, so: boom!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was discussed in the DVD commentary conversation between actress [Amanda Tapping](https://33.media.tumblr.com/ecabc773c04309e00e139d3fafd9e1a4/tumblr_mpvx1dpLwL1s5r0jno1_500.gif) (Major Carter) and Executive Producer [Robert C. Cooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Cooper).

> **RH:** *Why would we kill them [the Asgard]? Well, to be honest with you, I think we wanted this episode to have an element of tragedy in it that
>   would reflect how **we** were feeling. Some people might say "Isn't it enough that the show
>   is ending, we're all sad about that...?"*
>
> **AT:** *What did the Asgard do wrong!? It's too much!!*
>
> **RH:** *I think that to us, **it was important that there be something of tremendous resonance that got the episode started, that
>   would make the characters feel the weight of what this episode was going to 
>   mean**.*

<sub><sup>Transcript mine. Edited for clarity</sup></sub>

Comment: It also made it seem to us the audience that the mission was successful. The asgard wouldn't share with us whilst they were alive because they would help out if it was something they felt needed them. With them dead and all their knowledge passing onto us the SGC's original mission of procuring the means to defend the Earth is now complete.

Comment: Also, the Asgard (weakened by their drawn-out war with the Replicators) were about to be invaded by Ori and probably wouldn't be able to fend them off at that time, help from Tau'ri or not. They chose to keep their information from being acquired by a powerful enemy.